# How to print each letter on new line

Tags: python-3.x

Doing some revision, how would I do this:

Using a while loop, write a Python program that displays each of the characters in “Hello” on a new line, with the letter number before each character, starting at 1.
e.g.

```
1: H
2: e
3: l etc.
```

This is what I have so far:

```
w = input("Please enter Word: ")
list = w.split()
print(list)

for r in list:
    print(r, '\t')
```

I can get it to split sentences but not words.

Comment: hi @DavidJamesSmith you should provide some code first

Comment: I have added edit. Hope that explains things a bit better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is simple using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), for example

```
word="Hello"
for index,letter in enumerate(word,1):
    print(index,":",letter)
```

output

```
1 : H
2 : e
3 : l
4 : l
5 : o
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
w = input("Enter a word: ")
for letter in w:
    print(letter)
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = 'hello'
for i in data:
     print(i , end="\n")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.